# Spring data Cassandra, Allow filtering

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE magazines.magazine_name (
    frequency smallint,
    magazine_id varchar,
    magazine_name varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (magazine_id,magazine_name)
);
```

Should I use allow filter annotation to have the following repository method get executed

```
@Query("SELECT * from magazine_name where magazine_id = ?0")
MagazineName findMagazineCQlQuery(String id);
```

because I get the folowing execption :

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException:Query; 
CQL[com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@c78c2039]; 
Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. 
If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING; 

nested exception is 
 com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException:
Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering 
and thus may have unpredictable performance. 
If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

By the way, I know that I can use query methods or even findById method, but actually I am just experimenting with cql quires and try to learn about it.

--update
The domain object

```
@Table(value = "magazine_name")
@Data
@Builder
public class MagazineName {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "magazine_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String magazineId;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "magazine_name", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Querying by partition key (`magazine_id`) does not require the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive, because node ownership of data *can* be determined.  Are you sure the correct `PRIMARY KEY` definition has been posted?

Comment: I wiil update the question with both My domain object and the exception stack trace

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai : The exception seems to be from the CQL driver:
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@c78c2039]; Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING;

Comment: Also, try that query through cqlsh directly, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @Aaron : yes, works fine

Comment: Creation Query created by Spring data : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS magazine_name
 (magazine_id text, magazine_name text, frequency smallint, PRIMARY KEY (magazine_id, magazine_name)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (magazine_name ASC);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the table exactly like yours and here is my repository. I can query without error.

**1. My Repository**

```
public interface IMagazineDao extends CrudRepository<Magazine, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * from magazine_name where magazine_id = ?0")
    Magazine findMagazineCQlQuery(String id);


}
```

**2. Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    private IMagazineDao magazineDao;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.magazineDao.save(new Magazine("magazine1", "name", (short) 1));
        this.magazineDao.findMagazineCQlQuery("magazine1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**3. Magazine class**

```
@Table(value = "magazine_name")
public class Magazine {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "magazine_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String magazineId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "magazine_name", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String name;

    @Column
    private Short frequency;

    public Magazine() {

    }
    public Magazine(String magazineId, String name, Short frequency) {
        this.magazineId = magazineId;
        this.name = name;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String getMagazineId() {
        return magazineId;
    }

    public void setMagazineId(String magazineId) {
        this.magazineId = magazineId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Short getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(Short frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
}
```